# Where are apt update and upgrade exit status codes documented?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

For a script I need to know the possible exit statuses of both

```
apt update
apt dist-upgrade
```

with their meaning. Googling did not help me to find documentation. May be it is only commented in the source code? But where?

Answer (score 2):

If there are errors `apt` [will always return `100`](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/aa56836331870d975c212a5df2f13db9ce3914bf/apt-private/private-cmndline.cc#L603).